# Spring MVC routes to wrong action

Tags: java, spring-mvc, url-routing

I have the following controller (following Rails naming convention)

```
@RestController("/vehicles")
public class VehiclesController {

    @GetMapping
    public Iterable<Vehicle> index(
        @RequestParam(defaultValue = "1") int page,
        @RequestParam(defaultValue = "25") int per
    ) {
        ...
    }

    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public Vehicle show(@PathVariable long id) {
        ...
    }

    @PostMapping
    public Vehicle create(@RequestBody Vehicle vehicle) {
        ...
    }

    @PatchMapping("/{id}")
    public void update(@PathVariable long id, @RequestBody Vehicle params) {
        ...
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/{id}")
    public void destroy(@PathVariable long id) {
        ...
    }

}
```

Every time I send the request

```
GET /vehicles
```

I expect the request gets routed to the `index` method, but it actually is routed to the `show` method then failed to serve the content because the framework can't convert `"vehicles"` to a `long`. Here is the error message:

```
Failed to bind request element: org.springframework.web.method.annotation.MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'long'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "vehicles"
```

Is there anything wrong in my code? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `value` property of `@RestController` annotation is not a path prefix but a bean name. To give all annotated methods in your controller a prefix, annotate controller class with `@RequestMapping("/vehicles")`.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/vehicles")
public class VehiclesController {

    @GetMapping
    public Iterable<Vehicle> index(
        @RequestParam(defaultValue = "1") int page,
        @RequestParam(defaultValue = "25") int per
    ) {
        ...
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But I wonder why one needs a named controller instance.

Comment: All controllers are named anyway (class name starting with lower case letter). It's just a convention used across all similar annotations like `@Service`, `@Component`. You may want to change the name if a bean with same name is already registered, for example by 3rd party dependency. I had such a case with Spring Social but long time ago I cannot remember details.

Comment: Thanks a lot @MaciejWalkowiak
Wasted 2 hours on this
Forgot that RestController is a child of Component

Answer (score 0):

This is not correct.

```
@RestController("/vehicles")
```

The value ("/vehicles") is the name of the Component

In order to add a REST path you need *@RestController* annotation and *@RequestMapping* annotations on the class.

```
@RestController()
@RequestMapping(value = "/vehicles")
```

The value **/vehicles** is the suffix of your HTTP call.

You must change also the annotation on your *index* method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public Iterable<Vehicle> index(
    @RequestParam(defaultValue = "1") int page,
    @RequestParam(defaultValue = "25") int per
)
```

and everything should work as expected.

Comment: `value` property of `@RestController` is not a path. It's a component name: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RestController.html#value--